# Can I login to the Vault UI using a JWT bearer token in the Authorization header?

Tags: jwt, openid-connect, hashicorp-vault

Vault supports logging in [using a JWT](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/auth/jwt#jwt-login). I have a proxy in front of my Vault instance which manages an OIDC flow and injects a JWT as a bearer token in the Authorization header.

Instead of being presented with the Vault login screen, it would be convenient if Vault could parse the Authorization header and  automatically log me in -- is this possible?

I know Vault [supports Vault tokens in the Authorization header](https://www.vaultproject.io/api#authentication), but since I access my other dashboards using this JWT, it would be powerful for Vault to also interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know: no, not in the usual way with http-header authorization.
Vault would accept the jwt-token from oidc for login if the jwt-token comes as body/payload in json like this:

```sh
POST /v1/auth/jwt/login

{"jwt":"YOUR.JWT.TOKEN"}
```

Like written in vault docs:

```sh
curl --request POST \
     --data '{"jwt": "YOUR.JWT.TOKEN", "role": "demo"}' \
     http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/jwt/login
```

As header vault accepts the http-header `X-Vault-Token: s.XYZYXr3kuxR4`, which is a vault-token and not the oidc-jwt-token